# Problem with cards in a carousel (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5, card

I'm having an issue with cards in a bootstrap carousel. Please see the below CodePen link with my current (very unfinished) project.
https://codepen.io/robbiecorcoran/pen/eYMVvEN

```
<!-- RECOMMENDED -->
<div class="pt-lg-12 pb-lg-3 pt-8 pb-6">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mb-4 row">
            <div class="col">
                <h2 class="mb-0 mx-2 mt-5">Recommended for you</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <!-- GRAPHQL -->
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="card d-flex row justify-content-center" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="https://geeks-react.netlify.app/static/media/course-graphql.f5dec42e4ae0102ebffa.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">GraphQL: Introduction to GraphQL for beginners</h5>
                      <ul class="mb-3 list-inline">
                        <li class="list-inline-item">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-clock" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M8 3.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0V9a.5.5 0 0 0 .252.434l3.5 2a.5.5 0 0 0 .496-.868L8 8.71V3.5z"/>
                                <path d="M8 16A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16zm7-8A7 7 0 1 1 1 8a7 7 0 0 1 14 0z"/>
                              </svg> 2h 40m
                        </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bar-chart-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M1 11a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1v-3zm5-4a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v7a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H7a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V7zm5-5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2z"/>
                                  </svg> Advance
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" fill="#ffd700" class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" fill="#ffd700" class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" fill="#ffd700" class="bi bi-star-half" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M5.354 5.119 7.538.792A.516.516 0 0 1 8 .5c.183 0 .366.097.465.292l2.184 4.327 4.898.696A.537.537 0 0 1 16 6.32a.548.548 0 0 1-.17.445l-3.523 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256a.52.52 0 0 1-.146.05c-.342.06-.668-.254-.6-.642l.83-4.73L.173 6.765a.55.55 0 0 1-.172-.403.58.58 0 0 1 .085-.302.513.513 0 0 1 .37-.245l4.898-.696zM8 12.027a.5.5 0 0 1 .232.056l3.686 1.894-.694-3.957a.565.565 0 0 1 .162-.505l2.907-2.77-4.052-.576a.525.525 0 0 1-.393-.288L8.001 2.223 8 2.226v9.8z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" fill="#ffd700" class="bi bi-star" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M2.866 14.85c-.078.444.36.791.746.593l4.39-2.256 4.389 2.256c.386.198.824-.149.746-.592l-.83-4.73 3.522-3.356c.33-.314.16-.888-.282-.95l-4.898-.696L8.465.792a.513.513 0 0 0-.927 0L5.354 5.12l-4.898.696c-.441.062-.612.636-.283.95l3.523 3.356-.83 4.73zm4.905-2.767-3.686 1.894.694-3.957a.565.565 0 0 0-.163-.505L1.71 6.745l4.052-.576a.525.525 0 0 0 .393-.288L8 2.223l1.847 3.658a.525.525 0 0 0 .393.288l4.052.575-2.906 2.77a.565.565 0 0 0-.163.506l.694 3.957-3.686-1.894a.503.503 0 0 0-.461 0z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" fill="#ffd700" class="bi bi-star" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M2.866 14.85c-.078.444.36.791.746.593l4.39-2.256 4.389 2.256c.386.198.824-.149.746-.592l-.83-4.73 3.522-3.356c.33-.314.16-.888-.282-.95l-4.898-.696L8.465.792a.513.513 0 0 0-.927 0L5.354 5.12l-4.898.696c-.441.062-.612.636-.283.95l3.523 3.356-.83 4.73zm4.905-2.767-3.686 1.894.694-3.957a.565.565 0 0 0-.163-.505L1.71 6.745l4.052-.576a.525.525 0 0 0 .393-.288L8 2.223l1.847 3.658a.525.525 0 0 0 .393.288l4.052.575-2.906 2.77a.565.565 0 0 0-.163.506l.694 3.957-3.686-1.894a.503.503 0 0 0-.461 0z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item" style="color: #ffd700;">
                                <div class="fw-light">2.5</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <div class="fw-light">(1,500)</div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <div class="fw-bold">$500</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <div class="fw-light text-decoration-line-through">$600</div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <div class="align-items-center g-0 row">
                            <div class="col-auto col">
                                <img src="https://geeks-react.netlify.app/static/media/avatar-6.3905522d6589ed6dfcf0.jpg" alt="" class="rounded-circle avatar-xs">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-ms-2 col ps-3">
                                <span>Brooklyn Simmons</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto col">
                                <a class="bookmark" href="#">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bookmark" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                        <path d="M2 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h8a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.777.416L8 13.101l-5.223 2.815A.5.5 0 0 1 2 15.5V2zm2-1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v12.566l4.723-2.482a.5.5 0 0 1 .554 0L13 14.566V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H4z"/>
                                    </svg>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="carousel-item active col-3">
                <div class="card d-flex rowjustify-content-center" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="https://geeks-react.netlify.app/static/media/course-javascript.8afdeff32816e30422da.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                      <li class="list-group-item">An item</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                      <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item col-3">
                <div class="card d-flex justify-content-center" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="https://geeks-react.netlify.app/static/media/course-node.291fe1cded8ebab181ab.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                      <li class="list-group-item">An item</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                      <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item col-3">
                <div class="card d-flex justify-content-center" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="https://geeks-react.netlify.app/static/media/course-laravel.48ab426cd3f0adc40dd9.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                      <li class="list-group-item">An item</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                      <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item col-3">
                <div class="card d-flex justify-content-center" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="https://geeks-react.netlify.app/static/media/course-react.999d5d4b7ef4771200c2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                      <li class="list-group-item">An item</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                      <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>                  
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>




<script 
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

I'm trying to display 4 cards on a desktop, 2 cards on a tablet, and 1 on a mobile, but I cannot figure it out.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will probably need to use CSS media queries.

Something like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { /* modile */
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

Ref : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp